# django times out when accessing a specific object instance

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to troubleshoot a production issue where django times out when accessing a specific model instance but not other instances of the same class.

My production environment is Heroku using gunicorn with postgres as the database. Heroku is showing the following error in the logs (took out the sensitive bits):

```
Feb 21 20:26:20 [heroku-app-name] heroku/router: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="[url-path]" host=[my-host] request_id=[request-id] fwd="[fwd-stuff]" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http 
Feb 21 20:26:21 [heroku-app-name] app/web.1: [2019-02-22 04:26:21 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14) 
Feb 21 20:26:21 [heroku-app-name] app/web.1: [2019-02-22 04:26:21 +0000] [14] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14) 
Feb 21 20:26:21 [heroku-app-name] app/web.1: [2019-02-22 04:26:21 +0000] [20] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20
```

The specific url I'm accessing is simply displaying the model instance via the generic.DetailView class (simplified for brevity):

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'detail_view.html'
```

My production database only has a few dozen entries (still a new site) so as far as I can tell, I'm not actually overwhelming the server.

At this point, I'm not even sure where to go in order to figure out what's actually going wrong. The server times out EVERY time I access one specific instance of *MyModel* but works fine for every other instance.

Comment: Heroku requests are limited to 30 seconds. So if your request is taking more than that then it will show timeout error. So check if your app is heavy. And also you can increase that time.

Comment: @BidhanMajhi accessing other instances of this model takes significantly less than a second and there's nothing different about this instance (at least as far as I can tell). 

Is there a way to tell where django/heroku is timing out/getting stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while but I chased down the root cause to an infinite loop in my code. Under specific conditions, I was inadvertently causing an infinite loop to occur in a helper function that I was using to calculate and display the price of my thing.

bad code:

```
def my_cost_format(number, decimal_places=2, decimal="."):
    result = intcomma(number)
    result += decimal if decimal not in result else ""
    while len(result.split(decimal)[1]) != decimal_places:
        result += "0"
    return result
```

good code:

```
def my_cost_format(number, decimal_places=2, decimal="."):
    result = intcomma(round(number, decimal_places))
    result += decimal if decimal not in result else ""
    while len(result.split(decimal)[1]) != decimal_places:
        result += "0"
    return result
```

Lesson of the day: ALWAYS validate your input!